# Replacing certain characters with other characters

Tags: str-replace, discord.js

I'm trying to set up my first discord bot to be able to replace certain letters with other letters, but I am extremely new to coding in javascript.

```
function debunkCommand(arguments, recievedMessage) {
     if (arguments.length > 0) {
    function strReplace(){
            var myStr = argument;
            var newStr = myStr.replace(/l/gi, "w");
            var newStr = myStr.replace(/r/gi, "w");
        receivedMessage.channel.send(newStr)
    }
     } else {
    receivedMessage.channel.send("that's impossible to debunk")
      }
}
```

expected to be able to write "!debunk hello" and have the bot send back a message saying "hewwo"

Comment: Your `strReplace` function doesn't make sense. You create the function, but never call or return it. The function itself has a number of problems as well

Comment: `function debunkCommand(arguments, recievedMessage) {
     if (arguments.length > 0) {
    function strReplace(){
            var myStr = arguments;
            var newStr = myStr.replace(/[lr]/gi, "w");
            recievedMessage.channel.send(newStr)
    }
     } else {
    receivedMessage.channel.send("that's impossible to debunk")
      }
}
`

So like i said, im new, how would the return function change it? And here is the new code after some people helped me fix tiny things

Answer (score 0):

```
function debunkCommand(args, receivedMessage) {
    if (args.length) {
        /*
            arguments is an array of strings, doing 'arguments.join(" ")' will join these strings into one
            /[lr]+/gi will match any instances of 'l' or 'r'

            it's also a good idea to rename your "arguments" parameter to "args", since "arguments" is already a standart js object
        */
        receivedMessage.channel.send(args.join(" ").replace(/[lr]+/gi, "w"));
     } else {
        receivedMessage.channel.send("that's impossible to debunk");
    };
};
```